# Google DoubleClick missing ads for iOS

Tags: ios, admob, ads, double-click, google-dfp

I'm using Google DoubleClick for retrieving banner ads. I have a DFP account with registered ads that work (tested using a html page).

When using this code:

```
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"/36564804/app_banner_320x60";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
DFPRequest* request = [DFPRequest request];
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

I receive the following error in the debug console:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"297188a8e20f1d7405897fdfbe5fe7a0" ];
```

After setting the test device:

```
request.testDevices = @[ @"297188a8e20f1d7405897fdfbe5fe7a0" ];
```

I only receive dummy ads (like DoubleClick by Google that directs to developers.google.com).

**How can i actually display a real ad on my device ?**

Kind regards,

Dan